# Why is my app throwing a PopupWindow BadTokenException Error?

Tags: android

While my app is running, I get this error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

My code is:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nextround_popup, parent, false);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,(int) (width * .6), (int) (height * .8));  
Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_gradient));
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
}, 100L);
```

I found some helpful solutions on SO, but I didn't manage to get it solved.

Answer (score 1):

the reason for this error is PopupWindow showing need a token, but the view would not have the token until the Activity render complete. even if you make it delayed. as well as 100ms is short, but if make it longer, it seems stupid.
you can show PopupWindow in the method `onWindowFocusChanged`, when Activity render complete, this method will be called. like follows:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    //...
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        if(hasFocus){
            //show your PopupWindow
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    
    //...
}
```